# Appending <tr> into existing table with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

i try to insert a new row in my table, but i dont know why it insert additional < td> that i don't itemize.

My Table looks like

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>head1</th>
   <th>head2</th>
   <th>head3</th>
   <th>head4</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
    <tr id="test">
        <td>a1</td>
        <td>a2</td>
        <td>a3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>c1</td>
        <td>c2</td>
        <td>c3</td>
    </tr>            
 </tbody>
</table>
```

and i want to add a new row after #test

```
var row = '<tr>' +
   '<td>b1<td>' +
   '<td>b2<td>' +
   '<td>b3<td>' +
  '</tr>';
    $('#test').after(row);
```

but the result i get

```
<tbody>
  <tr id="test">
   <td>...
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>b1</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>b2</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>b3</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>...
```

I dont know why it place additional < td> in my table, does someone know why it doesn't work or where my mistake is?

I have create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uvhf2ua0/). Maybe it help you to understand my problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're not closing your `td` and thats the reason.  See here `<td style="background: red">b1<td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not closed your `td` try to replace this code:-

```
    var row = '<tr style="background: yellow">' +
                    '<td style="background: red">b1</td>' +
                    '<td style="background: green">b2</td>' +
                    '<td style="background: blue">b3</td>' +
                '</tr>';
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uvhf2ua0/1/)

Comment: @Hansinger haapy to help :)

Comment: write 5-10 minutes and format the text and only becaus i missed a "/" *yay*

Comment: @Hansinger some time it happend dnt wry... :)